# How to get the filesystem's root directory in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-os

Situation: I need to find the top level [root] directory of any operating system using the most Pythonic way possible, without system calls.

Problem: While I can check for the operating system using things like `if "Windows" in platform.system()`, I cannot be too sure if the drive letter is always `C:\` or `/` (the latter being unlikely). I also cannot possibly be sure that there are only Windows and *NIXes that needs to be catalog.

Question: Is there a way to get the top level directory of any operating system? Preferably using the `os` module since I am already using it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows doesn't have a single filesystem root.  The best you can do portably is to get the root of the filesystem's current directory (assuming the current directory is called `'.'`).

The expression to get that value is:

```
os.path.abspath('.').split(os.path.sep)[0]+os.path.sep
```

On Windows, if the current directory is anywhere under `C:`, that line will return `'C:\'`, while unix-like systems will return `'/'`.

I have no idea what VMS would give you.

Answer (score 12):

I believe `os.path.abspath(os.sep)` is close to what you are asking for.

Comment: This is probably true for all *popular* systems but if you want real portability, the code should also work on systems where this is not true. I vaguely believe VMS is different, for example.

Comment: @tripleee  And what would be your proactive, positive suggestion with respect to all other Systems (*having already offered your well-meaning criticism*)....? This Answer also clearly indicates to wit: ***i believe...*** **IS CLOSE TO** ***what you are looking for.***

Comment: If I had an answer I would post it as an answer. Do you find it problematic that I point out possible flaws for others who discover this answer and wonder whether it is good enough for their needs?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to get to the root directory.

```
file_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(file_path)
while (os.path.isdir(BASE_DIR)):
    if (BASE_DIR==os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)):
        break
    else:
        BASE_DIR=os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
        
print(f"{BASE_DIR} is the root directory")
```

First, BASE_DIR is obtained as the current working directory. Then, a while loop is used to go to the parent directory till it reaches the root directory.
When BASE_DIR is the root directory, again using os.path.dirname on the root directory gives the root directory itself. So, using that as a check, we can get the root directory.